# How do I SUM a column based on the match of 2 other columns with different sizes in Excel

Tags: excel

Hello fellow developers,

I'm currently working on an accounting worksheet, and I'm stuck in one formula (by the way, i don't want to use VBA).

I need the SUM of a database based on a column, in ONE CELL (this is very important because i will make this sum in a lot of other cells based on other criterias)

1 - I have one table column with 25k rows (it will increase every month).

2 - I have another table with 250 financial accounts,

3 - I need in one formula the sum of column 2 from table 1, that matches the column 1 from table 1 with the accounts from table 2,

I tried SUMPRODUCT( and SUM(IF(, but my problem was comparing two ranges with different sizes since one has 25k and another 250

Any Ideas?

Thanks ^^

Comment: `SUM(SUMIFS())`

Comment: well.. i didnt think of that.. thank you.. it worked =)